# VS Code and tasks with node

Tags: npm, visual-studio-code

Until now I used gulp for building typescript and sass files, but now due to a couple of new build steps I'd like to unify everything and use node as a single entry point (also node for running gulp tasks via npm run taskName).

tasks.json is quite simple, task `build` should run `npm run watch`:

```
{
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "command": "npm",
    "isShellCommand": true,
    "tasks": [
        {
            "taskName": "build",
            "isBuildCommand": true,
            "showOutput": "always",
            "isWatching": true,
            "args": [
                "run", "watch"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

package.json

```
"scripts": {
    "watch": "gulp default",
}
```

And the output:

```
gulp default build
[14:20:54] Using gulpfile PATH_TO/gulpfile.js
[14:20:54] Task 'build' is not in your gulpfile
[14:20:54] Please check the documentation for proper gulpfile formatting
npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.3.9600
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "run" "watch" "build"
npm ERR! node v0.12.2
npm ERR! npm  v2.7.4
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! 2@0.1.0 watch: `gulp default build`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the 2@0.1.0 watch script 'gulp default build'.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the 2 package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     gulp default build
npm ERR! You can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls 2
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
```

Based on the output, gulp is still somehow used even thought there is no sign of it in `tasks.json` (`gulpfile.json` exists in root directory and while searching for a solution I found that VS Code auto detects it, which I assume might be the problem?). Also `taskName` property is looks like automatically appended to command line as an argument which is wrong.

A smaller but working example (but it still runs gulp therefore typescript is compiled twice on each save):

```
{
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "command": "npm",
    "isShellCommand": true,
    "args": [
        "run", "watch"
    ],
    "showOutput": "always"
}
```

How can I have multiple tasks with in VS Code through npm?

Comment: I'm looking for a similar solution as well. Regarding the taskName appended to command line, look for `suppressTaskName` config property as mentioned [here](http://scottaddie.com/2015/10/07/harnessing-webpack-with-visual-studio-code/)

Comment: Also, have a look at [this](https://dlaa.me/blog/post/vscodenodetask) to see how to run npm scripts tasks from VS Code

Answer (score 19, accepted):

As mentioned in my comments, if you're looking to run npm scripts tasks from VS Code, look for [this article](https://dlaa.me/blog/post/vscodenodetask) that basically instructs to create a `.vscode\tasks.json` like the following:

```js
{
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "command": "npm",
    "isShellCommand": true,
    "suppressTaskName": true,
    "tasks": [
        {
        // Build task, Ctrl+Shift+B
        // "npm install --loglevel info"
        "taskName": "install",
        "isBuildCommand": true,
        "args": ["install", "--loglevel", "info"]
        },
        {
        // Test task, Ctrl+Shift+T
        // "npm test"
        "taskName": "test",
        "isTestCommand": true,
        "args": ["test"]
        },
        {
        // "npm run lint"
        "taskName": "lint",
        "args": ["run", "lint"]
        }
    ]
}
```

As an alternative, there's also a sample VS Code extension from Microsoft specifically aimed at detecting and running npm scripts items: [vscode-npm-scripts](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-npm-scripts)

Comment: but how do you run the tsc compiler, if the main command is npm? can't every task have its own command?

Comment: sorry, I don't understand it. If you have a grunt-/gulp- based toolchain, it should be grunt/gulp's duty to run tsc compiler under the cover, in one of its tasks/steps. If that's case, I guess you just invoke that specific grunt/gulp task from npm scripts. Please clarify more if I got that wrong

Comment: Thank you for your answer. At the time I wrote the question the solution above did not work, if I recall correctly. But now is the correct answer.

Comment: BTW thanks to @Izhaki for updating JSON to latest VS Code

Comment: Please update to version 2.0.0

Answer (score 1):

`.vscode/tasks.json` example using the latest v2.0.0 syntax:

```json
{
  "version": "2.0.0",
  "tasks": [
    {
      "type": "npm",
      "script": "start",
    },
    {
      "type": "npm",
      "script": "test",
    },
    {
      "type": "npm",
      "script": "lint",
      "problemMatcher": [
        "$eslint-stylish"
      ],
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: you can add `<!-- language: lang-js -->` to the beginning of your code block to add syntax highlighting

Comment: @HermanTheGermanHesse tada! (it's actually json, so I used: `<!-- language: lang-json -->`)

Comment: :D didn't know about JSON _the more you know_

Answer (score 0):

VS Code now has [Task Auto detection](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/tasks#_task-autodetection) for major systems like npm, gulp etc... so you may not have to define these tasks separately in your workspace anymore.

[image: Screenshot of Task-Auto detection in VS Code]